# Django - Player URL not found despite being in urls.py

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Over the last few days I have been working on building a Django web application for allowing users to make queries on a MLB Statistics database. I have some of the web app working fine, however I tried to implement a search function and ran into problems with the URL mapping. I tried to move on from this and instead work on getting the database to display information based on the link to the player that they click on, but I am running into the same issue with the URL's being dynamic based on the player's player_id. This portion only uses the People model which has player_id as its primary key.

Currently, I have an 'allPlayers.html' that lists every player in the database along with a link sending the player's `player_id` to the url as so:

**allPlayers.html**

```html
{% extends "base_template.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>MLB Stats All Players</h1>
  <p>Currently, there are : {{ num_players }} players listed in the database.</p>
  <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th></th>
      </tr>
      {% for player in players %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ player.name_first }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.name_last }}</td>
            <td>More on <a href="player/{{ player.player_id }}/">{{ player.name_first }} {{ player.name_last }}</a></td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
  </table>

{% endblock %}
```

And the corresponding view for 'allPlayers.html':

```py
def allplayers(request):
    """View function for allPlayers page of site."""

    # Generate counts of people object
    num_players = People.objects.count()
    players = People.objects.all()

    context = {
        'num_players': num_players,
        'players': players,
    }

    # Render the HTML template allPlayers.html w/ data in context variable
    return render(request, 'allPlayers.html', context=context)
```

With just the above I have successfully created a page on my web app that lists each player in the database along with a link, and notice that I am trying to send the `player_id` through `<a href='players/{{ player.player_id }}>`. Currently the `allPlayers` portion works fine. However, things go south when I add the following `playerInfo.html` and corresponding view:

**playerInfo.html**

```html
{% extends "base_template.html" %}

{% block content %}
  {% if results %}
    {% for player in results %}
      <p>{{ player.name_first }} {{ player.name_last }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

And the view:

```py
def player(request, pk=None):
    if pk is not None:
      print('Hello world')
      print('pk :', pk)
      #instance = get_object_or_404(People, player_id=pk)
      results = People.object.filter(player_id=pk)
      context = {
        "results": results
      }
      return render(request, "playerInfo.html", context)
    else:
        print('Hello')
        return render(request, 'playerInfo.html')
```

My idea was that the link noted earlier containing `{{ player.player_id }}` would match up with the following url and place the `player_id` value in for `pk`, as follows using the `<int:pk>` syntax instead of regex:

**polls/urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('allPlayers', views.allplayers, name='allplayers'),
    path('allTeams', views.allteams, name='allteams'),
    path('search/', views.search, name='search'),
    path('player/<int:pk>/', views.player, name='player'),
]
```

However, once I navigate to my 'allPlayers' page and click on one of the links for the player, say Hank Aaron (who has player_id aaronha01), I get the following **Page not found (404)** error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in baseballdb.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

polls/ [name='index']
polls/ allPlayers [name='allplayers']
polls/ allTeams [name='allteams']
polls/ search/ [name='search']
polls/ player/<int:pk>/ [name='player']
admin/
The current path, polls/player/aaronha01/, didn't match any of these.
```

I have been having trouble with this for quite a bit now. If anyone has any advice and can point me in the right direction of how I'm thinking about this incorrectly or has a solution for me that would be seriously greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: `path('player/<int:pk>/'` <--> `player/aaronha01/` does it look like **int**? And I doubt this href is correct `<a href="player/`

Comment: Wow what an embarassing oversight, my face is buried in my palms. And I'm fairly new to django (just started this as my first app the other day!), and by the href being incorrect do you mean I shouldn't have it pointing to `player/player_id` and instead just `player_id`? Sorry, the URL stuff has been the hardest part of this all for me, especially when I was reading through outdated stack overflow answers up until this morning. Either way, thank you so much!! That really was the issue, wow. Now I'm excited to get moving on this all over again! Thanks that really just made my day

Answer (score 1):

There is a mismatch between `<int:pk>` in your `path()`, which expects an integer, and your `player_id`, which is a string like `'aaronha01'`.

You can either use the pk everywhere, and have urls like `/player/17/`:

```
path('player/<int:pk>/', views.player, name='player'),

def player(request, pk):
    instance = get_object_or_404(People, pk=pk)
    context = {
        "instance": instance,
    }
    return render(request, "playerInfo.html", context)

# Use pk in template when constructing URL
<td>More on <a href="/player/{{ player.pk }}/">{{ player.name_first }} {{ player.name_last }}</a></td>
```

Or you can use `player_id` everywhere, and have urls like `/player/aaronha01/`.

```
path('player/<slug:player_id>/', views.player, name='player'),

def player(request, player_id):
    instance = get_object_or_404(People, player_id=player_id)
    context = {
        "instance": instance,
    }
    return render(request, "playerInfo.html", context)

# Use player_id in template when constructing URL
<td>More on <a href="/player/{{ player.player_id }}/">{{ player.name_first }} {{ player.name_last }}</a></td>
```

As a next improvement, you can start using the `{% url %}` tag so that you aren't hardcoding the URLs anymore.

```
<a href="{% url "polls:player" player.player_id %}">
```

In the above, I've assumed that you have `app_name='polls'` in your `polls/urls.py`, and that you have decided to use `player_id` instead of `pk` in your url pattern.

Comment: Hey man, I don't have the reputation to have my feedback displayed, but I plus-1'd your post, and if I could, I'd plus-2 it as your answer went above and beyond my expectations. Not only did you provide me answer, but with two, and then a little shove in the right direction on what to do next! Thanks so much, I really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

`path('player/<int:pk>/'` means only valid int `pk` would match. If your pk is not int and something like a valid `slug` - use `path('player/<slug:pk>/'` instead.

docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#path-converters

And my suggestion is to use `{{ player.get_absolute_url }}` or `{% url 'player' player.id %}` instead of building url manually.

Missing leading slash means "from here", not from website root:
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56840/what-is-the-purpose-of-leading-slash-in-html-urls

Comment: Hey, my rep is too low for my upvote to show but I want you to know that I upvoted and wish I could upvote again and again. Loved your initial comment and your full response is even more helpful. Thank you to everyone for so quickly answering my problem and pointing me in the right direction. I appreciate you taking the time out of your day to help me fix my problems!!